# Who should improve this question & how?

Tags: discussion

I think there's maybe a legitimate, on-topic question in [How can I improve our chance to get Greenlit on Steam?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/133940/how-can-i-improve-our-chance-to-get-greenlit-on-steam), but clearly there are some challenges.

At best, this is likely to have subjective answers. And to me, leading off with a link to your game, sort of looks like a guerrilla marketing attempt. Still, marketing & approval processes seem like they pose difficult challenges to developers & *if* this question could be saved, it may benefit many.

What I'm wondering is:

1. Is it solely on the OP to improve it, or is it okay for others to attempt to fix it?
2. What, if anything, can be done to better align it with GDSE?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it solely on the OP to improve it, or is it okay for others to attempt to fix it?

You are fine to improve a question that is not yours, but it is important to ensure such edits *are* an improvement, and that you still retain the core intent of the question. If the original asker decides they are unhappy with your edit, or other users decide your edit is *not* an improvement, it can easily be reverted; Assuming you did make the edit in good faith, it's no biggie.

In situations of blatantly off-topic questions where the user has made an effort in their attempts to ask the question, I would consider making more drastic changes, in an attempt to convert the question to an on-topic question that might still help the original asker. In these situations, I always leave a comment explaining why I made such an edit, detailing how the old question would be closed as off-topic and how the new question should still help the user find the information they were after.

---

> What, if anything, can be done to better align it with GDSE?

From what I can tell, *nothing*.

At the end of the day, the question asks "How can I improve the chances of being approved for Steam Greenlight". This raises two flags:

- First, we need to advise the user in *how* to get "greenlit". From what I can tell, this is *some sort* of popularity vote. While there is a concencus across multiple articles that popularity *does* have a big impact on who gets greenlit, there is broad speculation on minor impacts, such as how Steam manages their traffic to your site and how Steam may randomly select games of lesser popularity. Ultimately, your *opinion* of the exact conditions in which a game is greenlit goes a long way towards answering "how can I improve the chances of that happening".
- Given that we can at least agree that being greenlit is greatly based on popularity, we see that this question effectivley becomes 'how do I make my game more popular', or to a lesser degree, 'how do I make sure my game is good'.

For these reasons, I think it's fair to say that this question is unsuitable for the GDSE, and does not provide room for improvement.

---

> Well, what can I do, instead? *(inferred question)*

The question should be closed, but if the intention is to help the asker, there is certainly alternatives to consider.

- Comment on the original question and advise the user to try voicing their question on a relevant forum. Forums are generally far more flexible in their governing rules, and such questions are often welcomed. Furthermore, forums support greater dialog between individuals, which might allow for greater feedback.
- Comment on the original question, advising the user to try voicing their question in our chat room. This will still require the user to achieve a reputation score of 20 to unlock the "talk in chat" privilege, but I think it's fair to expect at least a little effort on the asker's behalf.
- While I do not agree with the inclusion of the asker's Greenlight page, as it only serves the purpose of advertisement, there is nothing stopping you from visiting the user's page and checking it out. Vote on it, comment on it, if it's good, tell us about it. Just not in a question format.

Comment: I agree with the speculation that greenlighting is in part a popularity vote & that what's popular is born from opinion. But there are things you can do to stack the deck in your favor. Identifying market opportunities, directing traffic, and advertising are not solely matters of luck & consumer whim; personally, those are the sort of things I would refocus the question on. I just didn't know how far an editor can go inferring authorial intent or if those specifics are on-topic enough for GDSE.

Comment: @Pikalek, to clarify, don't be afraid to break author intent if the original question would be closed, anyway. Just make sure you explain how we could not help with the original question, and how your changes make the difference between getting closed and getting an answer. Your changes should still reflect a question that would help the user. If you feel that your unsure, in this case would personally question the original askers efforts or wether they would even come back to look at and accept answers, consider that you might still have a good question. Why not ask it, yourself?

Comment: In regards to marketing, traffic, advertising etc (Analytics is another one) I would not consider these topics *specific* to Greenlight, in the context where they would be *applicable* to Greenlight. Any advice towards getting your game better coverage for Greenlight access could equally be for getting your game more coverage in general. While we have a [tag:marketing], most questions that actually ask 'how do I market' appear to be closed.

Comment: If such a question *was* written for the purpose of a good on-topic canonical answer, I would consider those with familiarity in the [tag:marketing] tag to be most on point. Unfortunately, our mods Josh and Byte are the only two users with more than 2 answers in that tag, and mods *tend* to have a lot on their plate.